# Post-Processing Script Slic3r replace value

Tags: perl, g-code

I created a script to give me the filament consumption of each Z layer, then I created a new variable "U" to provide me with this data, but I needed this variable to be at the beginning of each layer, where is "U" so I could know the filament consumption of this layer in the beginning of which layer.
Tks

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::Round;

my $consumedFilament=0;

while (<>) {
    # a regular expression for the G0/G1 commmand (click it to see what it does)
    if( /^G\[01\](\h+X(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(\h+Y(-?\d*\.?\d+))?
        (\h+Z(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(\h+E(-?\d*\.?\d+))?(\h+F(\d*\.?\d+))?
        (\h*;\h*(\[\h\w_-\]*)\h*)?/ ) {
        # the match variables, just readable
        my $X=$2, my $Y=$4, my $Z=$6, my $E=$8, my $F=$10, my $verbose=$12;
        if($E){
            # tracking how much filament we're using
            $consumedFilament=$E;
        }
        if( $Z ) {
            # print the consumed filament 
            print "\nU ".round($consumedFilament)."\n";
        }   
    }
    print;
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
    U 0                          **I need U0 to pass to U278**
    G1 Z20.000 F6000.000
    G1 X117.492 Y119.761 F6000.000
    G1 F6000
    G1 X120.027 Y117.335 E3.51353
    G1 X120.831 Y116.528 E4.65313
    ------------------------------------
    G1 X114.509 Y123.324 E274.53440
    G1 X116.543 Y120.923 E277.68582
    G1 X117.492 Y119.761 F6000.000
    layer;2
    
    
    U 278                           **I need U278 to pass to U241**
    G1 Z30.000 F6000.000
    G92 E0
    G1 X121.685 Y123.814 F6000.000
    G1 F6000
    G1 X123.236 Y122.221 E2.22788
    G1 X124.464 Y121.094 E3.89784
    --------------------------------
    G1 X120.479 Y125.171 E240.93648
    G1 X120.687 Y124.934 E241.25190
    G1 X121.685 Y123.814 F6000.000
    layer;3
    
    
    U 241                                **I need 241 to pass to U282** 
    G1 Z40.000 F6000.000
    G92 E0
    G1 X123.962 Y126.051 F6000.000
    G1 F6000
    G1 X126.580 Y123.484 E3.67782
    G1 X129.480 Y121.181 E7.39248
    G1 X132.605 Y119.194 E11.10716
    G1 X135.920 Y117.544 E14.82183
    G1 X139.390 Y116.250 E18.53649
    
    U 282
```

**original code**

```
; generated by Slic3r 1.3.0 on 2022-06-17 at 12:39:48

; external perimeters extrusion width = 11.00mm (1078.54mm^3/s)
; perimeters extrusion width = 14.00mm (1378.54mm^3/s)
; infill extrusion width = 12.50mm (1228.54mm^3/s)
; solid infill extrusion width = 14.00mm (1378.54mm^3/s)
; top infill extrusion width = 14.00mm (1378.54mm^3/s)




G21 ; set units to millimeters
G90 ; use absolute coordinates
M82 ; use absolute distances for extrusion
G92 E0
layer;0


U 0
G1 Z10.000 F6000.000
layer;1


U 0
G1 Z20.000 F6000.000
G1 X117.492 Y119.761 F6000.000
G1 F6000
G1 X120.027 Y117.335 E3.51353
G1 X120.831 Y116.528 E4.65313
G1 X123.606 Y114.381 E8.16666
G1 X124.489 Y113.663 E9.30625
G1 X127.474 Y111.817 E12.81978
G1 X128.427 Y111.195 E13.95937
G1 X131.589 Y109.671 E17.47291
G1 X132.602 Y109.153 E18.61250
G1 X135.905 Y107.968 E22.12604
G1 X136.967 Y107.558 E23.26562
G1 X140.376 Y106.725 E26.77916
G1 X141.474 Y106.428 E27.91875
G1 X144.952 Y105.956 E31.43228
G1 X146.076 Y105.775 E32.57187
G1 X146.261 Y105.768 E32.75779
G1 X149.583 Y105.669 E36.08542
G1 X150.720 Y105.608 E37.22500
G1 X154.219 Y105.869 E40.73854
G1 X155.356 Y105.926 E41.87813
G1 X158.809 Y106.552 E45.39167
G1 X159.934 Y106.727 E46.53125
G1 X163.303 Y107.710 E50.04479
G1 X164.403 Y108.003 E51.18439
G1 X167.650 Y109.333 E54.69791
G1 X168.714 Y109.738 E55.83750
G1 X171.804 Y111.400 E59.35104
G1 X172.820 Y111.915 E60.49064
G1 X175.720 Y113.891 E64.00416
G1 X176.676 Y114.509 E65.14375
G1 X179.353 Y116.777 E68.65728
G1 X180.239 Y117.492 E69.79689
G1 X182.665 Y120.028 E73.31042
G1 X183.472 Y120.831 E74.45000
G1 X185.619 Y123.606 E77.96353
G1 X186.337 Y124.489 E79.10313
G1 X188.183 Y127.474 E82.61667
G1 X188.805 Y128.427 E83.75627
G1 X190.329 Y131.589 E87.26979
G1 X190.847 Y132.602 E88.40938
G1 X192.032 Y135.905 E91.92291
G1 X192.442 Y136.967 E93.06250
G1 X193.275 Y140.376 E96.57604
G1 X193.572 Y141.474 E97.71562
G1 X194.044 Y144.952 E101.22917
G1 X194.225 Y146.076 E102.36874
G1 X194.232 Y146.261 E102.55468
G1 X194.331 Y149.583 E105.88229
G1 X194.392 Y150.720 E107.02190
G1 X194.131 Y154.219 E110.53543
G1 X194.074 Y155.356 E111.67501
G1 X193.448 Y158.809 E115.18854
G1 X193.273 Y159.934 E116.32815
G1 X192.290 Y163.303 E119.84167
G1 X191.997 Y164.403 E120.98126
G1 X190.667 Y167.650 E124.49480
G1 X190.262 Y168.714 E125.63438
G1 X188.600 Y171.804 E129.14793
G1 X188.085 Y172.820 E130.28751
G1 X186.109 Y175.720 E133.80104
G1 X185.491 Y176.676 E134.94063
G1 X183.223 Y179.353 E138.45417
G1 X182.508 Y180.239 E139.59378
G1 X179.972 Y182.665 E143.10731
G1 X179.169 Y183.472 E144.24687
G1 X176.394 Y185.619 E147.76041
G1 X175.511 Y186.337 E148.90002
G1 X172.526 Y188.183 E152.41354
G1 X171.573 Y188.805 E153.55315
G1 X168.411 Y190.329 E157.06667
G1 X167.398 Y190.847 E158.20627
G1 X164.095 Y192.032 E161.71980
G1 X163.033 Y192.442 E162.85939
G1 X159.624 Y193.275 E166.37293
G1 X158.526 Y193.572 E167.51250
G1 X155.048 Y194.044 E171.02606
G1 X153.924 Y194.225 E172.16562
G1 X153.739 Y194.232 E172.35156
G1 X150.417 Y194.331 E175.67917
G1 X149.280 Y194.392 E176.81878
G1 X145.781 Y194.131 E180.33230
G1 X144.644 Y194.074 E181.47188
G1 X141.191 Y193.448 E184.98542
G1 X140.066 Y193.273 E186.12503
G1 X136.697 Y192.290 E189.63856
G1 X135.597 Y191.997 E190.77814
G1 X132.350 Y190.667 E194.29167
G1 X131.286 Y190.262 E195.43126
G1 X128.196 Y188.600 E198.94481
G1 X127.180 Y188.085 E200.08439
G1 X124.280 Y186.109 E203.59792
G1 X123.324 Y185.491 E204.73752
G1 X120.647 Y183.223 E208.25106
G1 X119.761 Y182.508 E209.39065
G1 X117.335 Y179.973 E212.90418
G1 X116.528 Y179.169 E214.04376
G1 X114.381 Y176.394 E217.55730
G1 X113.663 Y175.511 E218.69690
G1 X111.817 Y172.526 E222.21043
G1 X111.195 Y171.573 E223.35002
G1 X111.113 Y171.406 E223.53594
G1 X109.671 Y168.411 E226.86356
G1 X109.153 Y167.398 E228.00315
G1 X107.968 Y164.095 E231.51669
G1 X107.558 Y163.033 E232.65628
G1 X106.725 Y159.624 E236.16981
G1 X106.428 Y158.526 E237.30940
G1 X105.956 Y155.048 E240.82293
G1 X105.775 Y153.924 E241.96252
G1 X105.669 Y150.417 E245.47606
G1 X105.608 Y149.280 E246.61565
G1 X105.869 Y145.781 E250.12918
G1 X105.926 Y144.644 E251.26877
G1 X106.552 Y141.191 E254.78231
G1 X106.727 Y140.066 E255.92190
G1 X107.710 Y136.697 E259.43544
G1 X108.003 Y135.597 E260.57502
G1 X109.333 Y132.350 E264.08856
G1 X109.738 Y131.286 E265.22814
G1 X111.400 Y128.196 E268.74168
G1 X111.915 Y127.180 E269.88127
G1 X113.891 Y124.280 E273.39481
G1 X114.509 Y123.324 E274.53440
G1 X116.543 Y120.923 E277.68582
G1 X117.492 Y119.761 F6000.000
layer;2


U 278
G1 Z30.000 F6000.000
G92 E0
G1 X121.685 Y123.814 F6000.000
G1 F6000
G1 X123.236 Y122.221 E2.22788
G1 X124.464 Y121.094 E3.89784
G1 X126.287 Y119.576 E6.27387
G1 X127.550 Y118.638 E7.84959
G1 X129.757 Y117.167 E10.50634
G1 X131.032 Y116.416 E11.98951
G1 X133.299 Y115.231 E14.55215
G1 X134.647 Y114.617 E16.03530
G1 X136.849 Y113.737 E18.41132
G1 X138.429 Y113.206 E20.08128
G1 X140.712 Y112.561 E22.45730
G1 X142.339 Y112.199 E24.12726
G1 X144.676 Y111.795 E26.50328
G1 X146.332 Y111.605 E28.17324
G1 X148.699 Y111.448 E30.54926
G1 X150.365 Y111.432 E32.21922
G1 X152.735 Y111.523 E34.59524
G1 X154.395 Y111.681 E36.26520
G1 X156.742 Y112.020 E38.64123
G1 X158.376 Y112.351 E40.31118
G1 X160.676 Y112.932 E42.68720
G1 X162.266 Y113.432 E44.35715
G1 X164.402 Y114.218 E46.63707
G1 X166.021 Y114.915 E48.40303
G1 X168.149 Y115.962 E50.77904
G1 X169.601 Y116.782 E52.44900
G1 X171.527 Y117.994 E54.72892
G1 X172.966 Y119.012 E56.49486
G1 X174.754 Y120.420 E58.77480
G1 X176.079 Y121.583 E60.54072
G1 X177.906 Y123.373 E63.10339
G1 X178.906 Y124.464 E64.58652
G1 X180.537 Y126.435 E67.14915
G1 X181.417 Y127.626 E68.63229
G1 X182.737 Y129.597 E71.00831
G1 X183.584 Y131.032 E72.67827
G1 X184.769 Y133.299 E75.24092
G1 X185.383 Y134.647 E76.72407
G1 X186.263 Y136.849 E79.10008
G1 X186.794 Y138.429 E80.77004
G1 X187.439 Y140.712 E83.14607
G1 X187.801 Y142.339 E84.81604
G1 X188.205 Y144.676 E87.19206
G1 X188.395 Y146.332 E88.86200
G1 X188.552 Y148.699 E91.23802
G1 X188.568 Y150.365 E92.90797
G1 X188.477 Y152.735 E95.28400
G1 X188.319 Y154.395 E96.95397
G1 X187.980 Y156.742 E99.32999
G1 X187.649 Y158.376 E100.99994
G1 X187.068 Y160.676 E103.37596
G1 X186.568 Y162.266 E105.04592
G1 X185.782 Y164.402 E107.32584
G1 X185.085 Y166.021 E109.09179
G1 X184.081 Y168.063 E111.37171
G1 X183.140 Y169.726 E113.28564
G1 X181.954 Y171.608 E115.51356
G1 X180.988 Y172.966 E117.18350
G1 X179.521 Y174.829 E119.55952
G1 X178.480 Y176.009 E121.13527
G1 X176.627 Y177.906 E123.79206
G1 X175.536 Y178.906 E125.27518
G1 X173.565 Y180.537 E127.83780
G1 X172.374 Y181.417 E129.32094
G1 X170.403 Y182.737 E131.69698
G1 X168.968 Y183.584 E133.36693
G1 X166.701 Y184.769 E135.92958
G1 X165.353 Y185.383 E137.41273
G1 X163.151 Y186.263 E139.78874
G1 X161.571 Y186.794 E141.45870
G1 X159.288 Y187.439 E143.83473
G1 X157.661 Y187.801 E145.50470
G1 X155.324 Y188.205 E147.88072
G1 X153.668 Y188.395 E149.55067
G1 X151.397 Y188.546 E151.83058
G1 X149.635 Y188.568 E153.59652
G1 X147.265 Y188.477 E155.97255
G1 X145.605 Y188.319 E157.64251
G1 X143.352 Y187.995 E159.92243
G1 X141.624 Y187.649 E161.68836
G1 X139.417 Y187.092 E163.96829
G1 X137.734 Y186.568 E165.73423
G1 X135.337 Y185.676 E168.29688
G1 X133.979 Y185.085 E169.78002
G1 X131.688 Y183.948 E172.34262
G1 X130.399 Y183.218 E173.82580
G1 X128.392 Y181.954 E176.20183
G1 X127.034 Y180.988 E177.87178
G1 X125.030 Y179.399 E180.43443
G1 X123.921 Y178.417 E181.91757
G1 X122.221 Y176.764 E184.29359
G1 X121.094 Y175.536 E185.96355
G1 X119.576 Y173.713 E188.33957
G1 X118.583 Y172.374 E190.00952
G1 X117.263 Y170.403 E192.38555
G1 X116.416 Y168.968 E194.05551
G1 X115.354 Y166.955 E196.33544
G1 X114.617 Y165.353 E198.10137
G1 X113.737 Y163.151 E200.47740
G1 X113.206 Y161.571 E202.14735
G1 X112.586 Y159.381 E204.42728
G1 X112.199 Y157.661 E206.19321
G1 X111.811 Y155.419 E208.47314
G1 X111.605 Y153.668 E210.23907
G1 X111.448 Y151.301 E212.61509
G1 X111.432 Y149.635 E214.28505
G1 X111.523 Y147.265 E216.66108
G1 X111.681 Y145.605 E218.33103
G1 X112.020 Y143.258 E220.70706
G1 X112.351 Y141.624 E222.37702
G1 X112.932 Y139.324 E224.75304
G1 X113.404 Y137.824 E226.32877
G1 X114.324 Y135.337 E228.98554
G1 X114.915 Y133.979 E230.46869
G1 X116.052 Y131.688 E233.03131
G1 X116.782 Y130.399 E234.51447
G1 X118.046 Y128.392 E236.89049
G1 X119.012 Y127.034 E238.56045
G1 X120.479 Y125.171 E240.93648
G1 X120.687 Y124.934 E241.25190
G1 X121.685 Y123.814 F6000.000
layer;3


U 241
G1 Z40.000 F6000.000
G92 E0
G1 X123.962 Y126.051 F6000.000
G1 F6000
G1 X126.580 Y123.484 E3.67782
G1 X129.480 Y121.181 E7.39248
G1 X132.605 Y119.194 E11.10716
G1 X135.920 Y117.544 E14.82183
G1 X139.390 Y116.250 E18.53649
G1 X142.976 Y115.326 E22.25116
G1 X146.639 Y114.782 E25.96583
G1 X148.048 Y114.706 E27.38202
G1 X150.338 Y114.623 E29.68064
G1 X154.034 Y114.853 E33.39531
G1 X157.686 Y115.467 E37.10997
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please rephrase it. No input data provided, a guess what it could be might not reflect real data. If I understood you look to summarize parameter `E` and output it for each layer before coordinates/data for this layer.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

OP question requires clarification -- based on provided output and code some assumption was put into programming the code.

The code goes through the data and looks for lines with the `E` parameter which is stored in a variable. A `$text` block variable is filled up with read lines.

Once the line holds `layer` it is a trigger for the output of collected information, and the variables `$text` block reset to a new state.

When there is no any data left the collected data is output once more.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($text,$consumedFilament);

$consumedFilament=0;

while (<DATA>) {
    $text .= $_;
    $consumedFilament = $1 if /^G[01] X\d+.\d+ Y\d+\.\d+ E(\d+\.\d+)/;
    if( /^layer;/ ) {
        say "U" . int($consumedFilament+0.5);
        say $text;
        $text = '';
    }
}

say "U" . int($consumedFilament);
say $text;

exit 0;

__DATA__
G1 Z20.000 F6000.000
G1 X117.492 Y119.761 F6000.000
G1 F6000
G1 X120.027 Y117.335 E3.51353
G1 X120.831 Y116.528 E4.65313
------------------------------------
G1 X114.509 Y123.324 E274.53440
G1 X116.543 Y120.923 E277.68582
G1 X117.492 Y119.761 F6000.000
layer;2
G1 Z30.000 F6000.000
G92 E0
G1 X121.685 Y123.814 F6000.000
G1 F6000
G1 X123.236 Y122.221 E2.22788
G1 X124.464 Y121.094 E3.89784
--------------------------------
G1 X120.479 Y125.171 E240.93648
G1 X120.687 Y124.934 E241.25190
G1 X121.685 Y123.814 F6000.000
layer;3
G1 Z40.000 F6000.000
G92 E0
G1 X123.962 Y126.051 F6000.000
G1 F6000
G1 X126.580 Y123.484 E3.67782
G1 X129.480 Y121.181 E7.39248
G1 X132.605 Y119.194 E11.10716
G1 X135.920 Y117.544 E14.82183
G1 X139.390 Y116.250 E18.53649
```

Output

```
U278
G1 Z20.000 F6000.000
G1 X117.492 Y119.761 F6000.000
G1 F6000
G1 X120.027 Y117.335 E3.51353
G1 X120.831 Y116.528 E4.65313
------------------------------------
G1 X114.509 Y123.324 E274.53440
G1 X116.543 Y120.923 E277.68582
G1 X117.492 Y119.761 F6000.000
layer;2

U241
G1 Z30.000 F6000.000
G92 E0
G1 X121.685 Y123.814 F6000.000
G1 F6000
G1 X123.236 Y122.221 E2.22788
G1 X124.464 Y121.094 E3.89784
--------------------------------
G1 X120.479 Y125.171 E240.93648
G1 X120.687 Y124.934 E241.25190
G1 X121.685 Y123.814 F6000.000
layer;3

U18
G1 Z40.000 F6000.000
G92 E0
G1 X123.962 Y126.051 F6000.000
G1 F6000
G1 X126.580 Y123.484 E3.67782
G1 X129.480 Y121.181 E7.39248
G1 X132.605 Y119.194 E11.10716
G1 X135.920 Y117.544 E14.82183
G1 X139.390 Y116.250 E18.53649
```

Comment: Hello
the output you post is exactly what I need, I tried your script but it doesn't make any changes to the original code

Comment: Hello
ok i got it to work, rookie mistake
thanks a lot for the help, thanks again

Comment: hello , I would like to know how to make this script read and write the result in a file to choose,tks

Comment: Well, you can replace `<DATA>` with `<>` and run the script as `script.pl infile.dat > outfile.dat`.

Comment: Hello Polar bear, tks one more time .In the future I'll have to make some changes to my software, if you're interested I'll leave an email "antoniompcouto@gmail.com"